# Is there a post-build action in VS 2015 when using SSDT to build/deploy SSRS Reports?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

Is there was a way to add a post-build action for an SSRS Reporting Project. I need to make some slight modifications to my reports in order to deploy on my production environment vs my local development environment. Namely, edit the locations of certain shared datasets and shared data sources. I've kludged together a powershell script that makes the modifications for me, I would just like a way to automatically run this script when I deploy to Release vs Debug.

If there's a better way to do what I need to do, please let me know! I'm new to SSRS report development.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to change, you could use the global `ReportPath` in your expressions to check the location.

Comment: @StevenWhite I tried that. It doesn't have the granularity that I was hoping for. I need to put different shared data sources into different folders.

Also, I believe there was a bug. For some reason, the report dataset would get appended to the SharedDataSetReference twice. Mapped dataset should be in /foo/bar/SharedDataSet1, but the report would look at /foo/bar/foo/bar/SharedDataSet1. I eventually gave up, since everything needed to go in different folders anyway.